# hooks to run different setup and clean for each test case in mocha

Tags: hook, mocha.js

i am developing a mocha automation framework. in that there are two hooks beforeEach() and afterEach() which will executed for each test case. i have defined the test setup and cleanup in these hooks. but i have different setup and cleanup for each test case, so i cant able to use beforeEach() and afterEach().

```
 describe()
 {
      beforeEach(setup)   //test setup
     it(Test1)
     it(Test2)
     it(Test3)
     afterEach(cleanup)//test cleanup
  }
```

in the above code, each test follows different setup and cleanup. is there any other hooks or methods which satisfies this condition, i.e. hooks which allows to different setup and cleanup for individual test case?

Answer (score 1):

If setup and cleanup are truly different for each test, you should just do something like this:

```
function test1() {
  # Setup
  test1SetUp();

  # Execute code under test

  # Cleanup
  test1CleanUp(); 
}
```

Do you see (or have already encountered) any issues with that?

Comment: so this function test1() comes under it() test case right? if i make use of this, i dont need to use beforeEach() and afterEach() hooks ?

Comment: `test1` would be passed into `it` as in `it("should pass test1", test1)`. You can still use `beforeEach` and `afterEach` for setup and cleanup that's **common** to all tests, but only if you need to.